# LG Optimus G not recognized by Eclipse (Mac)

Tags: android, eclipse, device-driver

I'm trying to test an Android app that I am developing in Eclipse. I've tested this app on other devices, and now I am trying to connect an LG Optimus G (LG-P769). This device runs Android 4.1.2 (API 16). My project is set with a minSdkVersion=9 and a targetSdkVersion=14, so I think that I'm OK here.

However, Eclipse (and my Mac finder) do not recognize this device. I have USB debugging turned on, and there seems to be no Android driver available for Mac (which might be my problem??).

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can get Eclipse to recognize this device. I am current on all my Android SDK Manager updates, so I don't think that the problem lies there.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: Please forgive (and forget) this question. I traced the problem back to a defective USB hub. The phone is being recognized just fine. I'm so sorry to have wasted anyone's time.

Comment: It is all part of the process. +1 for reporting back!